# question about css and html

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to make a page with `DIV`s that have different positions? Here is an example:
[image: Page with DIVs having different positions.]

Comment: why would you make this hotch-potch?

Comment: @Coding-Freak That's part of design for website

Comment: oh. you must have stated that, else anyone would think that its just for fun...

Comment: Absolute positioning will achieve your desired layout.

Comment: @Neir0: but **why?** Has anyone demonstrated this arrangement to be a beneficial user-interface design? I'm not voting the question down, since the question itself appears reasonable, genuine and potentially useful, but I still don't understand the intent behind the desired result.

Comment: Don't underestimate the importance of **symmetry**.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you need to use absolute positioning, with a fixed width and height for each element.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS absolute positioning. You can find an explanation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
Basically it would look something like

```
#div1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:150px;
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
}

#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:120px;
    top:200px;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Create `absolute` positioned DIVs and set the `top` and `left` CSS parameters for each of them.

You may wrap them with a `relative` positioned div.

Answer (score 0):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yz9e4/

How does this work? http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

The beauty in my answer is `#boxContainer > div`, which means you can avoid specifying `position: absolute` for every single box.

**CSS:**

```
#boxContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px dashed #444;
    position: relative
}
#boxContainer > div {
    /* put properties common to all positioned divs here */
    position: absolute;
    background: #999;
    border: 2px dotted #444
}

#box1 {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px
}
#box2 {
    top: 200px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 125px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="boxContainer">
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
<div id="C"></div>
<div id="D"></div>
```

CSS

```
#A, #B, #C, #D {
    position: absolute;   
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#A {
    top: 20px;
    left: 45px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#B {
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#C {
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

#D {
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x3gZ/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#cont{
background:#ff0000;
postition:relative;
width:800px;
height:800px;
}
#inn{
background:#00ff00;
position:relative;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="cont">
<div id="inn" style="top:100px;left:100px;"></div>
<div id="inn" style="top:300px;left:100px;"></div>
<div id="inn" style="top:420px;left:170px;"></div>
<div id="inn" style="top:200px;left:400px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
```